# Can't update Windows 2008 server with WSUS installed on it

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I have installed WSUS on my Windows 2008 server. My issue is the following:

I get the error message: Windows could not search for new updates (80244019)

- I can get updates from WSUS.
- I tried almost everything on google but can't afford some since it's a production server.

I am wondering if I need to add my 2008 server in my updating list in WSUS. Download updates from WSUS and at the sime time, update the server itself.

Do you guys know if it's possible to download updates without WSUS for my 2008 server?

No Windows Firewall enabled.
No Antivirus software installed.

If you need more info, please let me know.

Regards,
D.

Comment: R0ca, what if you take your server off the OU where all the computers are, so the GPO won't apply to it ? Then you can manually set the AutoUpdate service point to MS update server (regedit or local policy) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I thought, the only way to update my 2008 server is by adding it to the WSUS updating list. A WSUS server cannot updates itself thru WindowsUpdate.com but only thru WSUS.

Comment: So you asked a question, put a bounty on it, then answered it your self. That is awesome! high five on the points.

Comment: Yhea, I know it was not my best shot... I finally get the answer from MS and this is not possible...

Thanks again for your help! honestly!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are in a Active Directory environment. When I set up my WSUS on a Win 2003 server, I also had to put out a little piece of group policy that Allowed Automatic Updates, and set the intranet update server to my local server. This is found in Computer Configuration>Windows Components>Windows Update. I don't know if this has changed at all. Have you pointed your systems to the local WSUS server?

Comment: Hi Skaughty,

I am pretty sure that the only way to update my windows 2008 server is by adding this server in my WSUS updating list. The point is that my manager asked to avoid that. We don't want to download the whole updates list for 2008 srv and we want to download updates from Windows Update. 

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 1):

If the 2008 server is running the WSUS server software, then WSUS handles the download of updates to its repository internally. You can check the status of this from the WSUS server console under Administrative Tools.

For the underlying server itself, it behaves just like any other client server and will talk to the WSUS installation to obtain its updates. It should show up just like any other client on the WSUS console.

If the problem is with WSUS itself not being able to obtain updates from the internet, run through the WSUS server configuration wizard (via the WSUS console) and there's a step that should test the connection out to the Internet. Problems here are usually due to firewall restrictions between the server and the Internet.

If the problem is with the server OS getting updates from the WSUS install, check the WSUS event log in c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\ and see if there's any more info about the error there.

If you want to reconfigure the server to go directly to Microsofts update service, and ignore the local WSUS service, edit the update settings in the registry under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Win dows\WindowsUpdate\AU

To reset this you can delete the AU key, and it will be re-initialised on a reboot.

If none of this solves the issue, next questions would be:

- How is the server 'tied' to the WSUS server? Via a group policy, or manually via a registry entry or the command line?
- What's the last 10 lines of reportingevents.log in c:\windows\softwaredistribution

Comment: Hi Chris, 

I thought that I need to add my 2008 server (which is the WSUS server) to update itselft by itself... Hope this make sense for you.

Then, I took a look in the registry but I don't see that key. There is no WindowsUpdate under Windows. It's a Windows 2008 server Standard SP2.

And I can't paste the 10 last lines because is too big. Want me to send by email?

Comment: Hi r0ca, just the last couple of lines should do the job. Forgot about the comment length limit ;)

Comment: {7819CC42-78BE-4329-A069-11A652935AFB} 2010-01-27 07:43:16:988-0500 1 148 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 0 80244019 AutomaticUpdates Failure Software Synchronization Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80244019.
{EA888ED4-21A0-418B-BA80-919F2674DDD9} 2010-01-27 12:43:26:116-0500 1 148 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 0 80244019 AutomaticUpdates Failure Software Synchronization Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80244019.

Comment: Thanks r0ca. So other clients are successfully talking to the WSUS install, and you can see the clients in the WSUS console? If so, are you attaching clients to WSUS with a group policy?

Comment: I'm in an AD environment and all of my clients are updating successfully to the WSUS server. I applied the GPO to the workstations OU. I also added my 2008 server to that OU and it receives updates from WSUS. But, this is not what I want. I want my server to download updates from windowsupdate website. I just can't find anything that allow me to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a Windows update - kb2720211.  Either install it manually or remove the WSUS group policy from the server, gpupdate /force, and then run Windows Updates.